# Showing different popups for different layers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, web-mapping, popup

I have multiple layers that have different pieces of information.
I have radio buttons for selecting layers and when layers selected I want to show different popups which different information for each layer.
I tried to give different id to each layers and put if statement for each popup function but not successful
here is my HTML codes :

```
<h2>
                    layers
                </h2>
                <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="IranGeoJSON"  id="vector">classify cities <br>
                <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="IranGeoJSON2" id="vector">random <br>
                <input type="radio" name="layerButton" value="UnTiled" id="raster">Raster Layer
                <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            
            </div>
            <div class="grid-2">
                <div id='js-map' class="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="overlay-container2" >
        <span class="overlay-text" id="feature-country-name"></span><br>
        <span class="overlay-text" id="feature-city-name"></span><br>
        <span class="overlay-text" id="feature-area-name"></span><br>
        <span class="overlay-text" id="feature-latitude-name" style="font-size:13px"></span><br>
        <span class="overlay-text" id="feature-longitude-name" style="font-size:13px"></span><br>
        
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-container" >
        <span class="overlay-text" id="Raster-Elevation"></span><br>
        <span class="overlay-text" id="Raster-latitude"></span><br>
        <span class="overlay-text" id="Raster-longitude"></span>
    </div>
    
    <script  src="./libs/v6.5.0-dist/ol.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js" ></script>
```

and here is main.js codes for popup:

```
 if(document.getElementById('raster').checked) {
    const overlayContainerElement2 = document.querySelector('.overlay-container');
    const overlayLayer = new ol.Overlay({
        element:overlayContainerElement2
    })
    map.addOverlay(overlayLayer);
    const overlayElevation = document.getElementById('Raster-Elevation');
    const overlayRasterLat = document.getElementById('Raster-latitude');
    const overlayRasterLon = document.getElementById('Raster-longitude');
   map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    var view = map.getView();
    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
    var url = UnTiled.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt['coordinate'],
        viewResolution,
        'EPSG:3857', 
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'}
      );
      //console.log(url);
      if (url) {
        fetch(url)
          .then(function (response) { return response.json(); })
          .then(function (html) {
            //console.log(html.features[0].properties.GRAY_INDEX);
            let RasterClickedCoordinate = evt.coordinate;
            var RasterLonLat =ol.proj.transform(RasterClickedCoordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
            var RasterLon = RasterLonLat[0];
            var RasterLat = RasterLonLat[1];
            //console.log(RasterLon)
            var Elevation = html.features[0].properties.GRAY_INDEX ;
            overlayLayer.setPosition(RasterClickedCoordinate);
            overlayElevation.innerHTML ='Elevation : ' + Elevation;
            overlayRasterLat.innerHTML = 'Lat : ' + RasterLat;
            overlayRasterLon.innerHTML = 'Lon : ' + RasterLon;
            
          });
      }
      
     });
    }
    
     else if(document.getElementById('vector').checked) {
    const overlayContainerElement = document.querySelector('.overlay-container2');
    const overlayLayer2 = new ol.Overlay({
        element:overlayContainerElement
    })
    map.addOverlay(overlayLayer2);
    const overlayFeatureCountryName = document.getElementById('feature-country-name');
    const overlayFeatureCityName = document.getElementById('feature-city-name');
    const overlayFeatureAreaName = document.getElementById('feature-area-name');
    const overlayLatitudeCoordinate = document.getElementById('feature-latitude-name');
    const overlayLongitudeCoordinate = document.getElementById('feature-longitude-name');
    map.on('click',function(e){
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel,function(feature , layer){
            let clickedCoordinate = e.coordinate;
            //console.log(feature.getKeys());
            //console.log(clickedCoordinate[1]);
            
            var LonLat = ol.proj.transform(e.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
            var Lon = LonLat[0];
            var Lat = LonLat[1];
            let clickedFeatureCountryName = feature.get('NAME_0');
            let clickedFeatureCityName = feature.get('NAME_1');
            let clickedFeatureAreaName = feature.get('NAME_2');
            let clickedLatitudeCoordinate = Lat;
            let clickedLongitudeCoordinate = Lon;
        
             
              
            //console.log(clickedFeatureCountryName , clickedFeatureCityName , clickedFeatureAreaName);
            overlayLayer.setPosition(clickedCoordinate);
            overlayFeatureCountryName.innerHTML ='Country : ' + clickedFeatureCountryName;
            overlayFeatureCityName.innerHTML = 'State : ' + clickedFeatureCityName;
            overlayFeatureAreaName.innerHTML = 'City : ' +clickedFeatureAreaName;
            overlayLatitudeCoordinate.innerHTML='LAT : ' + clickedLatitudeCoordinate;
            overlayLongitudeCoordinate.innerHTML='LON : ' + clickedLongitudeCoordinate;
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Both your `setPosition` calls are using the `overlayLayer`.  The second call should be using `overlayLayer2`.

Comment: setPosition? I think I don't understand your solution because setPosition 1 use (clicked coordinate) value and the second one use(raster clicked coordinate)

Comment: For raster you define `const overlayLayer` and for vector you define `const overlayLayer2`, but for both you have `overlayLayer.setPosition()` so you always show the raster overlay.